# A comment to my question and my response have disappeared

Tags: support, comments

I noticed today that a question that had been answered in a comment no longer had the comment or my response.

I understand that comments can be deleted by the original poster or can get deleted if a user deletes their account.

I am unclear why my response to his comment was also deleted:
[In Assassination Classroom, wouldn't killing Koro-sensei cause the earth to be destroyed?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66723/in-assassination-classroom-wouldnt-killing-koro-sensei-cause-the-earth-to-be-d)

I checked the wayback machine to confirm that this was the case since the comment and my response was made over a year ago.  I had little trouble finding the answer and my response there:
https://web.archive.org/web/20220501030109/https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66723/in-assassination-classroom-wouldnt-killing-koro-sensei-cause-the-earth-to-be-d?atw=1

I am unclear how my response got deleted.  Can someone check if I deleted my response?

I thought that the comment sounded good.  I will answer my own question with the answer (after confirming) if the comment was not removed by mistake.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without revealing any actors, your comment was flagged and deleted as "no longer needed" because the comments you replied to have been deleted, presumably because your comment alone might be confusing to others without any context.